# Call base method from native part of inherite (Android)

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, native

My classes hierarchy looks that

```
// Form is my own class 
// Dialog is android class "android/app/Dialog"

class Form extends Dialog
{
    @override
    onBackPressed()
    {
        /*IMPLEMENTATION HERE*/
    }
}
```

I've got the native part of Form class where I should call the super.onBackPressed();

if I try

```
 GetMethodID("android/app/Dialog", "onGetPressed", "()V");
```

it calls the From.onBackPressed() methon not the Dialog.onBackPressed();

if Someone could tell me how to call super.onBackPressed() without making stub function in java like

```
void superOnBackPressed()
{
    super.onBackPressed()
}
```

I would be sooooooo happy =)

Comment: Isn't the object model there to stop you doing that?

Answer (score 1):

```
CallNonvirtualVoidMethod(jobject, jclass, jmethodID);
```

Solve this problem.